# Use for applying weak_ptr to contents of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, memory-leaks, c++11

I'm trying to understand the `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, and `weak_ptr` that came in with c++11.

I've heard that `weak_ptr`'s would be nice for things like caching, and breaking cycles, and so on. I've heard that they work well with `shared_ptrs`.

But in this regard, what's the difference between `shared_ptrs` and `unique_ptrs`? Why does `weak_ptr` only get to be used with one and not the other? Why wouldn't I want to have a weak reference to something owned by someone else?

Answer (score 7):

A `weak_ptr` is technically a means to hang on to the reference counter of a set of `shared_ptr`s that manage some shared object. When the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed the object is destroyed, but its reference counter lives on as long as there are `weak_ptr`s to it. Thus via any still exising `weak_ptr` you can check whether the object still exists, or has been destroyed.

If it still exists then from the `weak_ptr` you can obtain a `shared_ptr` that lets you reference the object.

The main usage of this is to break cycles.

In particular, an object can contain a `weak_ptr` holding on to its own reference counter, which allows you to obtain a `shared_ptr` to the object from the object itself. That is, a `shared_ptr` that uses the same reference counter as other `shared_ptr`s to this object. Which is how `enable_shared_from_this` works.

`unique_ptr` doesn't have any reference counter, so it doesn't make sense to hang on to that non-existent reference counter.

Comment: "*The main usage of this is to break cycles.*" I disagree with this. The main use of `weak_ptr` is to access an object that you don't need to own, but might be deleted when you're not looking at it. There's a notion that the object may or may not still exist, that you have to check.

Comment: Thanks, I never really understood what the point of a weak pointer was, this made it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

The major point of a weak pointer is that you can try to make the pointer strong, that is owning:

```
auto strongPtr = weakPtr.lock();

if (strongPtr)
{
    // still existed, now have another reference to the resource
}
else
{
    // didn't still exist
}
```

Note the first path: *making a weak pointer stronger requires we take ownership of the object*.

This is why it doesn't make sense with `unique_ptr`: the only way to make the weak pointer strong is to *take* the resource from somewhere else, and for `unique_ptr` that would mean leaving that somewhere else with an unexpected null pointer. `shared_ptr` gets a pass because taking it really means sharing it.

Comment: Can't someone use a pointer without owning it? Why can't someone have a unique_ptr to something to say that they own it, and then give others somekindof_ptr's that will assert that it still exists? It seems like a common use case, and so I assumed unique_ptr would handle it, but why doesn't it?

Comment: @Verdagon: We already have a non-owning kind of pointer. It's called a *pointer*. We don't need a special type or syntax for it; it's built into the language. Smart pointers are all about ownership relationships. So if you don't want someone to own the pointer, pass a pointer.

Comment: oh! i thought the new types of pointers would almost completely make obsolete regular pointers. its interesting to see that they fit into the new scheme!

Comment: @Verdagon: For what it's worth, the closest in between idea I can think would be sensible is some sort of "watched" pointer, which is a pointer that has a single unique owner (like `unique_ptr`) but also has "watched" references (like `weak_ptr`) that can tell if the uniquely owned resource is still around. But without a way of actually getting to that resource, I can't see the use.

Comment: What if we had a uniquewatcher_ptr that a user could just .get(), and it would return NULL if the original unique_ptr is no longer around, and return a raw pointer if it is still around? seems like a valid use case, how would i do it correctly?

Comment: @Verdagon: That would work, but I wouldn't create it or recommend it because it would be woefully easy to make mistakes. Imagine you call get(), get a non-null pointer, but by some side effect on your next line that original `unique_ptr` releases its resource. Now your pointer is bad. Sounds like it could be easy to avoid but it requires some very careful walking! You'd effectively have to make sure *every* operation operates directly on `get()` and doesn't store it, but that's impossible to enforce and still not even safe. Much simpler to simply use `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`.

Comment: @Verdagon, noone has proposed making pointers obsolete, I don't know where you got that idea.  Although there is [a proposal for the world's dumbest smart pointer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to C++11 as well, so if someone knows better I would appreciate any corrections.

I think that there wouldn't be much of a reason to, otherwise, you'd use a `shared_ptr` since it would defeat the whole purpose of a `unique_ptr`. A `unique_ptr` has implied semantics that it has complete control over the object to which it points.